# Why a user can't just call the token contract for transfer and not the marketplace?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I have maybe a weird question.

But let's say there is contract of `T (token ERC721)` and contract of `M (marketplace)`. The marketplace has a method `.buy` which does a transfer of a token to the buyer, pays the seller and takes a fee.

In a made up situation my friend wants to transfer me a token, but not pay any fees. Can't he just call the contract of `T.safeTransferFrom` directly and not the `M.buy` which deducts money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. The [EIP 721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) specification only defines an interface. It is up to the tokens how they implement each function.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But f.e the method `safeTransferFrom` is external payable, in this case if I want to allow only to do transfers for `M` contract, I can have a require for the `msg.sender` which is `M.address`? And nobody will be able to do these calls?

Comment: @TomasEglinskas If `safeTransferFrom` have `require(msg.sender == MarketAddress)` then only `MarketAddress` will be able to call the transfer function. Or you can define an access list that will allowed to operate.